# How can I list all of the files in a directory with Perl?

Tags: perl, directory

Is there a function in Perl that lists all the files and directories in a directory?
I remember that Java has the `File.list()` to do this? Is there a comparable method in Perl?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

If you want to get content of given directory, and only it (i.e. no subdirectories), the best way is to use opendir/readdir/closedir:

```
opendir my $dir, "/some/path" or die "Cannot open directory: $!";
my @files = readdir $dir;
closedir $dir;
```

You can also use:

```
my @files = glob( $dir . '/*' );
```

But in my opinion it is not as good - mostly because glob is quite complex thing (can filter results automatically) and using it to get all elements of directory seems as a too simple task.

On the other hand, if you need to get content from all of the directories and subdirectories, there is basically one standard solution:

```
use File::Find;

my @content;
find( \&wanted, '/some/path');
do_something_with( @content );

exit;

sub wanted {
  push @content, $File::Find::name;
  return;
}
```

Comment: I always forget that readdir just returns a list of relative filenames, not the entire path!

Comment: Thanks for discouraging the use of globbing for this task. Another downside of using globbing for this is, that it will not find hidden files (those starting with a dot).

Answer (score 15):

this should do it.

```
my $dir = "bla/bla/upload";
opendir DIR,$dir;
my @dir = readdir(DIR);
close DIR;
foreach(@dir){
    if (-f $dir . "/" . $_ ){
        print $_,"   : file\n";
    }elsif(-d $dir . "/" . $_){
        print $_,"   : folder\n";
    }else{
        print $_,"   : other\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should check opendir for failure (opendir...or die "Error message: $!"). Also, am I missing something? What is Win32::GUI::DoEvents() doing here? (I don't see anything relevant in the question.)

Comment: this is the best way i dont want or wish to remember regular expresions for something that should be easy to do, i will use this to create a function like list($dir,"f"); for files "d" for directory, thanks for posting this

Answer (score 14):

readdir() does that.

Check http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html

```
opendir(DIR, $some_dir) || die "can't opendir $some_dir: $!";
@dots = grep { /^\./ && -f "$some_dir/$_" } readdir(DIR);
closedir DIR;
```

Answer (score 11):

Or [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/~nwclark/perl-5.8.9/lib/File/Find.pm)

```
use File::Find;
finddepth(\&wanted, '/some/path/to/dir');
sub wanted { print };
```

It'll go through subdirectories if they exist.

Answer (score 5):

If you are a slacker like me you might like to use the [File::Slurp](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurp#read_dir) module. The read_dir function will reads directory contents into an array, removes the dots, and if needed prefix the files returned with the dir for absolute paths

```
my @paths = read_dir( '/path/to/dir', prefix => 1 ) ;
```

Answer (score 3):

This will list Everything (including sub directories) from the directory you specify, in order, and with the attributes. I have spent days looking for something to do this, and I took parts from this entire discussion, and a little of my own, and put it together. ENJOY!!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --
print qq~Content-type: text/html\n\n~;
print qq~<font face="arial" size="2">~;

use File::Find;

# find( \&wanted_tom, '/home/thomas/public_html'); # if you want just one website, uncomment this, and comment out the next line
find( \&wanted_tom, '/home');
exit;

sub wanted_tom {
($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid,$rdev,$size,$atime,$mtime,$ctime,$blksize,$blocks) = stat ($_);
$mode = (stat($_))[2];
$mode = substr(sprintf("%03lo", $mode), -3);

if (-d $File::Find::name) {
print "<br><b>--DIR $File::Find::name --ATTR:$mode</b><br>";
 } else {
print "$File::Find::name --ATTR:$mode<br>";
 }
  return;
}
```

Comment: ... said every perl programmer ever