# How can I loop through files in a directory in Perl?

Tags: perl, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I list all of the files in a directory with Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045792/how-can-i-list-all-of-the-files-in-a-directory-with-perl)

I want to loop through a few hundred files that are all contained in the same directory.  How would I do this in Perl?

Comment: Isn't this question a duplicated of this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045792/how-can-i-list-all-of-the-files-in-a-directory-with-perl

Comment: @Leonardo Herrera Indeed, it is. Sorry, I did not remember that one. Voting to close.

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate.  The question asks how to loop through files in a directory.  The marked 'duplicate' asks how to list all the files in a directory.  Clearly different. Why mark as a duplicate?

Answer (score 53):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my @files = <*>;
foreach my $file (@files) {
  print $file . "\n";
}
```

Where

```
 @files = <*>;
```

can be

```
 @files = </var/www/htdocs/*>;
 @files = </var/www/htdocs/*.html>;
```

etc.

Comment: This will not list hidden files (those starting with a dot) on GNU/Linux and probably other similar operating systems.

Answer (score 23):

Enjoy.

```
opendir(DH, "directory");
my @files = readdir(DH);
closedir(DH);

foreach my $file (@files)
{
    # skip . and ..
    next if($file =~ /^\.$/);
    next if($file =~ /^\.\.$/);

    # $file is the file used on this iteration of the loop
}
```

Comment: thanks! I'd use `next if ($file =~ /^.+$/);` though, to avoid the second statement ;) .

Comment: @ashraf regex has to be /^\.+$/  instead of /^.+$/

Comment: @Rauf yes I think you're right! :)

Answer (score 13):

You can use [readdir](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#readdir-DIRHANDLE) or [glob](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#glob-EXPR).

Or, you can use a module such as [Path::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class::Dir#list-dir-children):

> Ordinarily `children()` will not include the self and parent entries . and .. (or their equivalents on non-Unix systems), because that's like I'm-my-own-grandpa business. If you do want all directory entries including these special ones, pass a true value for the all parameter:
>
> ```
> @c = $dir->children(); # Just the children
> @c = $dir->children(all => 1); # All entries
> ```
>
> In addition, there's a no_hidden parameter that will exclude all normally "hidden" entries - on Unix this means excluding all entries that begin with a dot (`.`):

```
@c = $dir->children(no_hidden => 1); # Just normally-visible entries
```

Or, [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#children):

> ```
> @paths = path("/tmp")->children;
> @paths = path("/tmp")->children( qr/\.txt$/ );
> ```
>
> Returns a list of `Path::Tiny` objects for all files and directories within a directory. Excludes `"."` and `".."` automatically.
>
> If an optional `qr//` argument is provided, it only returns objects for child names that match the given regular expression. Only the base name is used for matching:

```
@paths = path("/tmp")->children( qr/^foo/ );
# matches children like the glob foo*
```

Getting the list of directory entries into an array wastes some memory (as opposed to getting one file name at a time), but with only a few hundred files, this is unlikely to be an issue.

`Path::Class` is portable to operating systems other than *nix and Windows. On the other hand, AFAIK, its instances use more memory than do `Path::Tiny` instances.

If memory is an issue, you are better off using `readdir` in a `while` loop.

Comment: and reead_dir removes . and .. for you, and if need be can prefix the directory into the filename