# Is there any selection function in perl?

Tags: bash, perl

In bash script, we know that there is a select function that can list all the files in current directory with number for selection. Once choose the number, can get the value behind.

```
select application in */; do test -n "$application" && break; echo ">>> Invalid Selection"; done
```

Is there any similar function in perl?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2149386/2970947

Comment: Hi, I know how to list all files in a directory but I hope can have number in front for selection.