# Regex for input file in Perl

Tags: regex, xml, perl

I have a Perl code and i want to introduce my input files by regex.
I have several files that start with CD* and I want to have an action on each file (The action is converting each file in an XML format) My Perl works fine for one specific file, which I address my input file by full name.
Now my Questions are:

**Firstly I don't know how to introduce my files as regex in Perl?**
with the below introduction, I get an error.

```
$filename=~ /^CD*/i
```

**and secondly, how to save each file?**
I want to have my bash code on each input file and have a separate output for each input?

Best Regards,
Sara

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149368/how-can-i-loop-through-files-in-a-directory-in-perl

Comment: I didnt understand. It was different from my question.

Comment: The case you shared is compeletely different!

Comment: If you want to sort files using a regex you need to loop through the files first.

Comment: i don't want to sort my files! I have said above, i want to run specific bashscript on a specific file names (starts with CD) in my perl code and have a function on it.